# Correlation of Events(AlerKey) basis its Time(First_Occurred) on the Nodes (Area). Which event is more likely to happen as a result of past event?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbilh.png)

Correlation of Events(AlerKey) basis its Time(First_Occurred) on the Nodes (Area). Which event is more likely to happen as a result of past event with reference to the Time on the Node in R tool ?

Also if we can show the correlation percentage and at what confidence we can say this event will happen as a result of previous event  ?

I have already grouped Nodes and sorted Occurrence time in ascending order.

Data has 5 columns, Node, AlertKey, count, FirstOccurence & LastOccurrence.

"Node    AlertKey        Count    FirstOccurrence       LastOccurrence
A      HouseKeeping     40      2020-05-08 15:48:21   2020-05-18 12:12:40
A      Loss_Of_Sec      6       2020-05-14 12:49:43   2020-05-18 00:13:48
A      Loss_Of_Signal   3       2020-05-09 17:02:56   2020-05-17 23:05:34
A      Not_Reach        9       2020-05-11 10:24:03   2020-05-14 12:55:53
A      Node_Isolation   5       2020-05-11 10:24:03   2020-05-14 12:55:52
C      Degraded_Signal  10      2020-05-15 13:40:48   2020-05-17 15:26:46
C      Degraded_Signal  10      2020-05-15 13:40:48   2020-05-17 15:26:46
C      Remote_Defect    1       2020-05-11 18:20:09   2020-05-18 18:20:08
C      Loss_Frame       35      2020-05-09 12:21:10   2020-05-09 12:21:13"

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming related question; might be more appropriately asked at [https://stats.stackexchange.com/](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I want to get this done on R tool